# Postgres integer out of range

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql

I am getting a `value "1574799549227" is out of range for type integer` error when trying to insert into a brand new table on a brand new database. I am using node with the pg module.

```
db
.query(`INSERT INTO users (uuid, email, password, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, to_timestamp($4 / 1000), to_timestamp($4 / 1000))`,
            [uuid, email, password, Date.now()])
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This is the table

```
CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    id serial,
    uuid uuid,
    email character varying,
    password character varying,
    created_at timestamp with time zone,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    CONSTRAINT user_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I have also tried reseting the sequence number for the id field

Comment: Use bigserial or bigint instead of serial or uuid

Comment: @nacho I have switched it to bigserial, it doesn't fix the issue. It also shouldn't be an issue as the database and table are brand new..

Comment: What value do you have at $1??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. Turns out that it was the timestamps I had. I was using `to_timestamp($4 / 1000)` when I should of been using `to_timestamp($4 / 1000.0)`

Answer (score 1):

Please see the official documentation for [Numeric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-numeric.html).  Serial datatype has a range of 1 to 2147483647.

SERIAL columns are stored as INTEGERs, giving them a maximum value of 231-1. So after ~2 billion inserts, your new id values will no longer fit therefore please ensure that you are inserting that many rows during the lifetime of the table.

If you are altering table, please remember to use `BIGINT` rather than `BIGSERIAL`.

`ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN id TYPE BIGINT;`

Most likely cause is that the value in `id` column is out of this range.

Comment: Maybe I didnt express it clearly. The table is new, there is no data in it already. Id is serial so it auto increments so theoretically it should be at 1

Comment: Have you tried recreating the table with col id as BIGSERIAL or altering the table to change the id col to BIGINT?

Comment: Yes, as I explained to nacho above. I have tried switching them